# PyQt5: Progress Indicator as Overlay

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I am again playing around with PyQt5 and this time I am stuck with how to add something like a ["circular progress indicator"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3W2Vo.png) to my gui when the execution of a method takes a bit longer.

In order to do this, I have a (super) simple gui with just one button. When the button gets clicked, the application prints for 15 seconds "hello world!" to the console (this is just to see that it's actually doing something).

**My question now is:** How can I "overlay" a progress indicator to my gui when the execution of a method takes more than e.g. 4 seconds (until the method finishes, then the progress indicator should disappear again)? I have a sample script for a progress indicator from [here](https://github.com/mojocorp/QProgressIndicator). But unfortunately, I am lost when it comes to adding it to my toy example. Any help here would be very much appreciated.

I'm using: `PyQt5.6.0`, `Python3.5.2`

My code:

**design.py** (the gui file)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(105, 140, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

**main.py**: (the main script):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import time
from design import Ui_MainWindow


class ToyEx(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.gorepeat)

    def gorepeat(self):
        """
        print sth for 15 seconds
        """
        end_time = time.time() + 15 * 1
        print(end_time)
        while time.time() < end_time:
            print('hello world!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ToyEx()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**progress_indicator.py**: (the code for the progress indicator, adapted from [here](https://github.com/mojocorp/QProgressIndicator/blob/master/QProgressIndicator.py))

```
"""
adapted to PyQt5 from:

  Author: Jared P. Sutton <jpsutton@gmail.com>
  License: LGPL
  Note: I've licensed this code as LGPL because it was a complete translation of the code found here...
    https://github.com/mojocorp/QProgressIndicator

  sourcecode from here: https://github.com/mojocorp/QProgressIndicator

"""

import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import time


class QProgressIndicator(QWidget):
    m_angle = None
    m_timerId = None
    m_delay = None
    m_displayedWhenStopped = None
    m_color = None

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Call parent class constructor first
        super(QProgressIndicator, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialize Qt Properties
        self.setProperties()

        # Intialize instance variables
        self.m_angle = 0
        self.m_timerId = -1
        self.m_delay = 40
        self.m_displayedWhenStopped = False
        self.m_color = Qt.black

        # Set size and focus policy
        self.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)

        # Show the widget
        self.show()

    def animationDelay(self):
        return self.delay

    def isAnimated(self):
        return (self.m_timerId != -1)

    def isDisplayedWhenStopped(self):
        return self.displayedWhenStopped

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(20, 20)

    def startAnimation(self):
        self.m_angle = 0

        if self.m_timerId == -1:
            self.m_timerId = self.startTimer(self.m_delay)

    def stopAnimation(self):
        if self.m_timerId != -1:
            self.killTimer(self.m_timerId)

        self.m_timerId = -1
        self.update()

    def setAnimationDelay(self, delay):
        if self.m_timerId != -1:
            self.killTimer(self.m_timerId)

        self.m_delay = delay

        if self.m_timerId != -1:
            self.m_timerId = self.startTimer(self.m_delay)

    def setDisplayedWhenStopped(self, state):
        self.displayedWhenStopped = state
        self.update()

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.m_color = color
        self.update()

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        self.m_angle = (self.m_angle + 30) % 360
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if (not self.m_displayedWhenStopped) and (not self.isAnimated()):
            return

        width = min(self.width(), self.height())

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        outerRadius = (width - 1) * 0.5
        innerRadius = (width - 1) * 0.5 * 0.48

        capsuleHeight = outerRadius - innerRadius
        capsuleWidth = capsuleHeight * .23 if (width > 32) else capsuleHeight * .35
        capsuleRadius = capsuleWidth / 2

        for i in range(0, 12):
            color = QColor(self.m_color)

            if self.isAnimated():
                color.setAlphaF(1.0 - (i / 12.0))
            else:
                color.setAlphaF(0.2)

            painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
            painter.setBrush(color)
            painter.save()
            painter.translate(self.rect().center())
            painter.rotate(self.m_angle - (i * 30.0))
            painter.drawRoundedRect(capsuleWidth * -0.5, (innerRadius + capsuleHeight) * -1, capsuleWidth,
                                    capsuleHeight, capsuleRadius, capsuleRadius)
            painter.restore()

    def setProperties(self):
        self.delay = pyqtProperty(int, self.animationDelay, self.setAnimationDelay)
        self.displayedWhenStopped = pyqtProperty(bool, self.isDisplayedWhenStopped, self.setDisplayedWhenStopped)
        self.color = pyqtProperty(QColor, self.getColor, self.setColor)


def TestProgressIndicator():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t_end = time.time() + 10 *1
    progress = QProgressIndicator(None)
    progress.setAnimationDelay(70)
    progress.startAnimation()

    # Execute the application
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestProgressIndicator()
```

**EDIT**:
I tried something again by using the `threading` module when including the progress indicator. Below is the updated code:

**design.py** (gui file, includes progress indicator):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'design.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(105, 140, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))


class QProgressIndicator(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    m_angle = None
    m_timerId = None
    m_delay = None
    m_displayedWhenStopped = None
    m_color = None

    def __init__(self, parent):
        # Call parent class constructor first
        super(QProgressIndicator, self).__init__(parent)
        # palette = QPalette(self.palette())
        # palette.setColor(palette.Background, Qt.transparent)
        # self.setPalette(palette)

        # Initialize Qt Properties
        self.setProperties()

        # Intialize instance variables
        self.m_angle = 0
        self.m_timerId = -1
        self.m_delay = 40
        self.m_displayedWhenStopped = False
        #self.m_color = Qt.black
        self.m_color = QtCore.Qt.transparent

        # Set size and focus policy
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)

        # Show the widget
        self.show()

    def animationDelay(self):
        return self.delay

    def isAnimated(self):
        return (self.m_timerId != -1)

    def isDisplayedWhenStopped(self):
        return self.displayedWhenStopped

    def getColor(self):
        return self.color

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(50, 50)

    def startAnimation(self):
        self.m_angle = 0

        if self.m_timerId == -1:
            self.m_timerId = self.startTimer(self.m_delay)

    def stopAnimation(self):
        if self.m_timerId != -1:
            self.killTimer(self.m_timerId)

        self.m_timerId = -1
        self.update()

    def setAnimationDelay(self, delay):
        if self.m_timerId != -1:
            self.killTimer(self.m_timerId)

        self.m_delay = delay

        if self.m_timerId != -1:
            self.m_timerId = self.startTimer(self.m_delay)

    def setDisplayedWhenStopped(self, state):
        self.displayedWhenStopped = state
        self.update()

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.m_color = color
        self.update()

    def timerEvent(self, event):
        self.m_angle = (self.m_angle + 30) % 360
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if (not self.m_displayedWhenStopped) and (not self.isAnimated()):
            return

        width = min(self.width(), self.height())

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

        outerRadius = (width - 1) * 0.5
        innerRadius = (width - 1) * 0.5 * 0.48

        capsuleHeight = outerRadius - innerRadius
        capsuleWidth = capsuleHeight * .23 if (width > 32) else capsuleHeight * .35
        capsuleRadius = capsuleWidth / 2

        for i in range(0, 12):
            color = QtGui.QColor(self.m_color)

            if self.isAnimated():
                color.setAlphaF(1.0 - (i / 12.0))
            else:
                color.setAlphaF(0.2)

            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
            painter.setBrush(color)
            painter.save()
            painter.translate(self.rect().center())
            painter.rotate(self.m_angle - (i * 30.0))
            painter.drawRoundedRect(capsuleWidth * -0.5, (innerRadius + capsuleHeight) * -1, capsuleWidth,
                                    capsuleHeight, capsuleRadius, capsuleRadius)
            painter.restore()

    def setProperties(self):
        self.delay = QtCore.pyqtProperty(int, self.animationDelay, self.setAnimationDelay)
        self.displayedWhenStopped = QtCore.pyqtProperty(bool, self.isDisplayedWhenStopped, self.setDisplayedWhenStopped)
        self.color = QtCore.pyqtProperty(QtGui.QColor, self.getColor, self.setColor)
```

**main.py** (updated):

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from threading import Thread, Timer
from design import Ui_MainWindow, QProgressIndicator
import time


class ToyEx(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.threadfuncts)

    def threadfuncts(self):
        Thread(target=gorepeat).start()
        Timer(4, Thread(target=test_progressindicator).start())  # <-- THIS DOES NOT WORK!


def gorepeat():
    """
    print sth for 15 seconds
    """
    end_time = time.time() + 15 * 1
    while time.time() < end_time:
        print('hello world!')


def test_progressindicator():
    progress = QProgressIndicator(None)
    progress.setAnimationDelay(70)
    progress.startAnimation()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ToyEx()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

But when I run this code, it crashes after one or two seconds already. Shouldn't the method `threadfuncts()` handle the threading in a way that the first function ( `gorepeat()`) gets called and 4 seconds later the second function (`test_progressindicator()`) gets called (and then they run in parallel)? If I define `test_progressindicator()` as another function that simply prints sth to the console, then the threading "kind of" works (the delay of 4 seconds doesn't work -- which is another point here that I do not understand why it does not work).

Again, if anyone could help me with this here, I'd appreciate it very much...